# Regex for NGINX Rewrite on Profile URLs

Tags: regex, nginx

I am working on NGINX rewrites. I want to match if this exists and if it does not just take what is there and set it as $2.

```
rewrite ^/profile/(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*-u)|(^\s*$))([0-9]+)$ /profile/$2/ redirect;
```

This is not quite working correctly, right now it would match /a-u4/ but I want it to also match /4/.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: The `(^\s*$)` is never matched (it matches the start of a string, 0+ whitespaces, end of string - it is impossible to match such a pattern inside a string), you may remove it. Try `^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*-u)?([0-9]+)$` and replace with `/profile/$1/`

Comment: When I looked it up, it said that is how you match blank.

Comment: No, you do not understand anchors. Remove `^` and `$` then to match 0+ whitespaces with `\s*`.

Comment: Obviously, I do not understand or I would not be asking how.  When I google searched it, that's how it said to make it work.  It;s not working, so my question is how do I make it work?

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*-u|\s*)([0-9]+)$ /profile/$1/ redirect;`. I think you can even replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` with `[\w-]`

Comment: I'm not sure which strings you want to match at all but if you want /a-u4/ and /4/ as well (so that a-u is optional), you could use:
`^/profile/(?:[\w-]*-u)?(\d+)$ /profile/$1/`
I'm not sure if \s is necessary or even ever matches anything, because it will be escaped and replaced by `%20` or `+`, maybe you could explain what kind of urls you want to redirect

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, unfortunately neither of these worked.

Comment: With what urls are you testing it? How can we help without knowing it :D Which url didn't work?

Comment: Best the question shows an example and the reg ex tells you exactly what is expected.  /profile/Name-u000/   OR /profile/000/

Comment: The regex can't possibly say what's expected or it would work :-) you do need to state what you're trying to achieve. It's not clear what you want to capture in to $2 and that needs stating.

Comment: I understand why you would want to rewrite `/profile/name-u123` to `/profile/123`, but how come you want to rewrite `/profile/123` to `/profile/123` as well? This would give you a cycle; the rewriting won't terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I understand from the comments you want to match /profile/Name-u000/ or /profile/000/

This regex will work:

```
^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+-u)?([0-9]+)/$
```

This puts whatever number is matched (the 000 part) in to $2.

Making the complete rule:

```
rewrite ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+-u)?([0-9]+)/$ /profile/$2/ redirect;
```

But don't use it! It will just create a redirect cycle, if this is what you want to do. But I need...

**Clarification**

I understand this may need tweaking to be exactly what you want, as I'm not clear what you're trying to capture to $2. Let me know and I'll update my answer. If it is just the number you want to capture, then you are wanting to redirect /profile/000/ to itself with no change, so no need to do that part, and just /profile/Name-u000/ needs redirecting. Let me know if I'm missing something.

**How The Regex Works**

```
^/profile/
```

Match the start of the string followed by /profile/.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+-u)?
```

Optionally match 1 or more letters, numbers, underscores or dashes followed by -u and capture it to $1. The question mark after the parentheses is what makes it optional. Remember that the first part (before -u) could even start or finish with an underscore or dash, which you may or may not want.

```
([0-9]+)
```

Match 1 or more numbers and capture to $2.

```
/$
```

Finish matching with a forward slash at the end of the string.

Comment: Not sure why the answer has been marked down. Feedback would be appreciated if there is a problem.